# ml-engine: package-uris cannot install package

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to install a package when training my model on ml-engine with the file structure:

```
/ml_engine
  setup.py
  /trainer
    __init__.py
    task.py
    model.py
```

I've ran: `python setup.py sdist` to create a package, and uploaded the package to a bucket.

Finally,

```
gcloud alpha ml-engine versions create m_0_03 \
--model {model_name} \
--origin gs://{model_location} \
--runtime-version 1.10 \
--framework SCIKIT_LEARN \
--python-version 3.5 \
--package-uris gs://{package_location} \
--model-class trainer.model \
```

However, it gives a error:

```
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  
"Failed to load model: User-provided package dist.tar.gz failed to install: Command '['python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib', '--no-cache-dir', '/tmp/custom_code/dist.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Error code: 0)"
```

I tried downloading the same package, and it successfully installs locally.

Comment: Can you kindly contact cloudml-feedback@google.com and we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google currently has an issue with creating versions of custom ML models.